# Execute LEFT JOIN using GroupJoin, throws error (bug?)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

All I want to do is a simple left join using EF Core. I want rows where the key exists, and NULLs where it doesn't, just like I'd get with a SQL query.

I also want it to use Fluent calls, because that's what the rest of the application uses.

I am keen to find out why this works:

```
var entites = await (
        from b in Context.Buildings
        join r in Context.Regions
        on b.BuildingId equals r.BuildingId into regions
        from r in regions.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { b, r } 
    ).ToListAsync();
```

but this does not:

```
var entities = await Context.Buildings
    .GroupJoin(
        Context.Regions,
        building => building.BuildingId,
        region => region.BuildingId,
        (building, region) => new { building, region }
    )   
    .SelectMany(z => z.region.DefaultIfEmpty(), (building, region) => new { building, region })
    .ToListAsync();
```

The code compiles fine but the latter throws a runtime error every time:

> System.InvalidOperationException: variable 'region' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sql.Models.Region]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

The `region` in question is in the `(building,region)` parameter list in the `GroupJoin`.  Nothing I do can get it to recognize that parameter. I see some other SO questions and bugs reported, but they're years old. This is EF Core 6.0.4. All those bugs were fixed years ago, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, there is a bug, but not in EF Core. The problematic query with method syntax is not equivalent of the working one using the query syntax.

The problem is that here

```cs
.SelectMany(z => z.region.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (building, region) => new { building, region }
)
```

the type of `building` variable is not `Building`, but the same as `z`, i.e. the result of the `GroupJoin` operator.

The correct operator is:

```cs
.SelectMany(z => z.region.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (z, region) => new { z.building, region }
)
```

and now the query works the same way as the other.

Query syntax makes these intermediate variables transparent for you, that's why it is preferred syntax for queries with manual joins. *"want it to use Fluent calls, because that's what the rest of the application uses"*. I've seen this many times and totally disagree. Both syntaxes can be used interchangeable, and even mixed. Since both have pros and cons, just use the one which is appropriate for the specific query.

Also note that EF Core still doesn't support `GroupJoin` LINQ operator well (even though they should), probably because  all types of LINQ joins can be represented with `SelectMany` and correlated subquery. Which also makes method syntax more readable and less error prone, since it is a single method and does not need intermediate variables. For instance, your query could be written as:

```cs
Context.Buildings
    .SelectMany(building => Context.Regions
        .Where(region => region.BuildingId == building.BuildingId)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(), // left join. remove it to get inner join
        (building, region) => new { building, region }
    );
```

And of course, the best in EF Core is to not use manual joins at all, and use navigation properties which provide the necessary joins automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  Regarding "because that's what the rest of the application uses", I have also come to the conclusion that this self-imposed restriction is foolish.  Use the tool that is right for the job.